# Subscribtion to FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED is running twice

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In symfony 3 I have subscribed to

**FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED**
to fill a second table with address data and writing a log.

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

class RegistrationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $em;

    private $container;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em,ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => [
                ['onRegistrationCompleted',0]
                ],
            ];
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $address = new Address();
        $address->addAddress($user);
        $this->em->persist($address);
        $this->em->flush();

        $this->container->get('app.logging')->write('Anmeldung',array('customer'=>$user->getId()));
    }


}
```

services.yml:

```
app.registration_listener:
    class: 'AppBundle\EventListener\RegistrationSubscriber'
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_subscriber}    

app.logging:
       class: AppBundle\Util\LogHandler
       arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
       public: true
```

After submitting the registration form, FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED is triggered, but it is running twice, because address data and log data are written twice.

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by myself.

In services.yml of symfony 3.3 I used the option
**autoconfigure: true**,
so services and event subscribers are loaded automatically.

That is why the event was triggered twice.